# How to check if HTML input textbox is below a certain number using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox, onkeydown

I want to validate an input box using javascript to prevent users from entering above a certain number. I have already done the validation for numbers. How do I prevent users from entering above a certain  number? For example, users cannot enter more than 24.

I have tried `onkeydown="return (this.value<25)"`

HTML

```
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey
                || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false)
                || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
                || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9)
                || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40)
                || (event.keyCode==46)
                || (parseInt(this.value, 10)<25))">
```

Comment: I don't think the input's value gets updated until after the key event, but in any case I wouldn't try to do it on keydown (or keyup or keypress), for two reasons: (1) It would be a bit weird from the user's point of view that the number keys higher than 2 only work some of the time, and it may take a while before they realise why; (2) Without using the keyboard the user can still paste in higher numbers (or letters). You should validate `onsubmit` of the form and/or `onchange` of the field.

Comment: hmm i think i will take your suggestion! Mods can close this question!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use radix:

```
return (parseInt(this.value, 10)<25)
```

Comment: I have tried this.. but it doesnt work, take a look at my updated question. Thanks.